# WordPress Custom Post Type and Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have the following URL structure I'd like to achieve for this website:

http://www.website.com/about/members/service-affiliate/company-name

I created a custom post type called "members", which contains the member "company-name".

I've also created a custom taxonomy which has the slug /about/members

The custom taxonomy has categories which you can select member type. Right now this member is a service-affiliate type of member.

When I create this combination, the I cannot display an archive page, taxonomy, nor a template on the following URL structures within my domain:
/about/members
/about/members/service-affiliate

Is there a way I can do this? Right now I'm getting a 404 no matter how I configure it.

Comment: can anyone help me with this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create, one archive page.

Ex: archive-custompost.php

Update Permalink structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can go in this way ...
create a template page named archive-members.php

as far as your taxonomy is concerned to create a template named taxonomy-member.php 
and your posts will show fine ...

change your taxonomy name if your names are different than a member like if your taxonomy name is service it will become taxonomy-service.php 
hope, that works for you